# Link-to route but render it into current routes outlet

Tags: javascript, ember.js, routes

In my scenario I have an `items` route with a `item` nested route that looks like

```
this.route('items',function(){
    this.route('item',{path:':item_id'});
});
```

This nested route renders a component that slides overtop of the content of the parent route so you can swipe it away. I have another route called `watch-list` that displays items similar to `items` but has more items being shown, I want the same behavior as how `item` renders a component that slides overtop of the parent content to it can be swiped away. But if I link to `items.item` it leaves this route to go over to `items` so that the `item` route does the slide over animation thing. So to get around that I added an `item` nested route to `watch-list` like so

```
this.route('watch-list',function(){
    this.route('item',{path:':item_id'});
});
```

Which does the same thing as `items` and `items.item` so now it renders the same component that `items.item` does and does my sliding animation overtop of the parent `watch-list` content. The issue is now I have two routes that show single items and I really want to have `items.item` be my single item route no matter where the list of items that linked to it lives.

Is there a way I can link-to `items.item` to show a single item, and have the URL change to reflect that, but have it render inside my `watch-list` route so that the single item component will slide over top of the `watch-list` content and not go and render `items` first?

Also here is what each template more or less looks like hopefully for some better clarity

```
// items template
{{#each sortedItems key="id" as |item|}}
    {{#link-to "items.item" item}}
        ...
    {{/link-to}}
{{/each}}
{{outlet}}

// items.item template
{{item-component item=model}}
```

Watch list is the same layout so I get the same effect

```
// watch-list template
{{#each sortedItems key="id" as |item|}}
    {{#link-to "watch-list.item" item}}
        ...
    {{/link-to}}
{{/each}}
{{outlet}}

// watch-list.item template
{{item-component item=model}}
```

Comment: Do you really need the `watch-list` thing as route? Your solution seems a bit against the idea of routes as unique identifiers of resources. If `watch-list` is for different visualization of the items, than a component and the use of query params would be better, I think.

Comment: I agree but it's what the boss wants, doesn't like the query params thing, we want clean URLs